# Как правильно: власти предержащие или власть предержащие?

Tags: грамотная-речь

**1) В литературе используются оба варианта:**

а) Мы не знаем, на что имеем право, а **власть предержащие** этим пользуются. [Людмила Григорьева. Фонд «Право матери»-2004 (2004) // «Адвокат», 2004.12.01] - 16 примеров.

б) Казалось, что **власти предержащие** ждут чего-то еще. [Василий Аксенов. Таинственная страсть (2007)] - 34 примера.

**2) Но нет единого мнения, какой из них правильный:**

а) Большинство редакторов, с которыми мне приходилось иметь дело неизменно исправляли "власти предержащие" на "власть предержащие".  В современной устной и письменной речи **это устойчивое выражение употребляется нередко в ошибочной, искаженной форме**, а именно: "власть предержащие"

[Власти предержащие | alex-k.livejournal.com](http://alex-k.livejournal.com/3378.html)

б) **Модная сейчас в газетах идиома «власть предержащие», то есть власть держащие, власть имущие,** впервые зафиксировано в тексте «Остромирова евангелия» (1056).  Тысячу лет назад слово «власть» означало – страна, область (сравните – волость), а слово «предержащие» означало – управляющие. Древнее значение оборота «власть предержащие» – управляющие страной, волостью, новое значение – власть имущие. Значение изменилось, форма осталась прежней.

[Внутренняя деформация фразеологизмов | Выкидалка.Ру](http://vikidalka.ru/3-84834.html)

Comment: Я бы предложила использовать это словосочетание как эмоциональную оболочку в форме одного слова "властьпредержащие", ведь речь отнюдь не о констатации факта, а об отношении к этому факту.

Comment: Ответ Грамоты.ру можно посмотреть по ссылке http://gramota.ru/biblio/magazines/gramota/frazeologia/28_365

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) В 2а приведен сомнительный текст: автор, так много общавшийся с разными редакторами, не расставляет, как надо, запятые. Наверно, и редакторы такие же.

2) В 2б *идиома зафиксирован**о***, автор не очень внимательный, а там и до *власть предержащих* недалеко. Для справки: в тексте, где, по мнению автора, **идиома** употреблена впервые ("прѣдерьжащоу обѣ власти"), "предержащие власти" — **свободное сочетание**. Т. е. автор элементарно ***не знает предмета*** своих рассуждений. Более того, если, согласно автору, форма осталась прежней, должно быть как раз власт**и** предержащие.

Вариант *власть предержащие*, нередко встречающийся в современных средствах информации, является ошибочным и не рекомендуется для употребления ("Русская фразеология", А. К. Бирих со ссылкой на Колесова).

Answer (score 3):

Говорили о том уже сто раз. Некогда искать, поэтому отвечу.

1б) - правильно.

Кстати, единственный авторитетный автор. Дело не в имени, и не запятых, а в том, у кого из цитируемых авторов есть языковое чутьё.

Власть ***предержащая*** (какая), поэтому во множественном ***власти предержащие***.

Трактовка "[лица], власть предержащие" требует эллипсиса, поэтому слишком современна для Остромирова Евангелия. Если будет точный текст, посмотрю, а так - не верю.

ЗЫ в 2б) вообще слишком много "оригинального", чтобы относиться серьезно.
"небоже" - такой формы нет, нищий - убоже. 
"Пенаты" - название усадьбы Репина. От него, видимо, и пошло. Разумеется правильная форма - к родным пенатам.

(+)-------------
Я нашел более или менее полный анализ всего выражения.
[И ещё раз о властях предержащих, или Что такое «крылатые слова»? | gramota.ru](http://gramota.ru/biblio/magazines/gramota/frazeologia/28_365)

Приводить весь нет никакой возможности, тем более что там очень много сторонних рассуждений. Но вот выдержки.

> Надо сказать, редакция совету автора не последовала. Более того,
>   ответила вполне определенно: «К сожалению, неправильное словосочетание
>   „власть предержащие“ все ещё проникает в газету. Корректорам газеты
>   следует безжалостно изгонять его с газетной полосы. А г-ну Андрееву мы
>   рекомендовали бы следовать нормам русского языка и пользоваться
>   словосочетаниями „предержащие власти“ и „предержащая власть“».

....

> О том, что словосочетание власти предержащие относится к разряду
>   крылатых слов, можно узнать из книги Н. С. Ашукина и М. Г. Ашукиной
>   «Крылатые слова». Здесь вы прочитаете, что выражение власти
>   предержащие — цитата из новозаветного текста Послания апостола Павла к
>   римлянам. Глава XIII этого Послания начинается призывом к христианам в
>   гражданской жизни «проявлять свое благоговение перед Богом в
>   повиновении установленным от Бога властям». В Библии это место
>   читается так: «Всяка душа властем предержащим да повинуется». Эту же
>   цитату при толковании слова предержащий приводит в своем словаре и
>   Владимир Даль

Думаю, исчерпывающе.

Там же есть и подробный анализ причин и истории ошибочного написания. Хотя история и очень древняя (тянется с первых переводов Нового Завета на русский), Остромирово Евангелие там не упоминается.

Comment: А как вы думаете, какие перспективы у правильного сочетания "власти предержащие"? Возможно,  пользователи в конце концов  перестанут различать "власть предержащие" и "власть имущие", так как  это устойчивые сочетания со сходным содержанием, хотя и разным происхождением. И стоит ли в этом случае настаивать  на разных формах, ведь в языке много других проблем.  Иногда мне кажется, что имеет место "культурное самоутверждение" правильно говорящих, разделение общества на культурную часть и не сосем такую по не очень важному критерию.  Но возможно, я ошибаюсь, а ревнители чистоты языка  правы.

Comment: @Sibylla, вопрос, конечно, имеет право на существование. Случаи, когда выражения переосмыслялись, не редкость. Но тут, хотя я провидец плохой, что-то не верится мне, что подобное переосмысление - жизненно. Т.е. оно будет до бесконечности  приводится разными авторами, но пока есть люди достаточно грамотные, чтобы разобраться в исходном смысле,  нормативным оно не станет.

Answer (score 2):

[Архив службы русского языка](https://www.slovari.ru/default.aspx?p=1012):

> Есть два выражения: **власть предержащая** и **власти предержащие**.
>   Поэтому можно сказать: "Мнение народа будет донесено до ВЛАСТИ
>   ПРЕДЕРЖАЩЕЙ" или "Мнение народа будет донесено до ВЛАСТЕЙ
>   ПРЕДЕРЖАЩИХ", но нельзя "Мнение народа будет донесено до ВЛАСТЬ
>   ПРЕДЕРЖАЩИХ".

См.: [Розенталь Д.Э., Теленкова М.А. Словарь трудностей русского языка.](http://dazor.narod.ru/russkie/slovari/trudnostej/slovar-trudnostej_0536.htm)

В ["Литературном редактировании текста"](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/56.htm) (XXXV. §144. 2) Розенталь напоминает, что

*власть предержащие* - ошибка, следует: *власть предержащая*;

в зависимости от значения следует: *с властью предержащей* или *с властями предержащими*.

---

Много лет назад я отвечала на этот вопрос - придумалась запоминалка, хоть и нерифмованная:

*власть нельзя предержать* (кому-либо), *предержит только она сама*.

Answer (score 1):

Я предполагаю, что ошибка возникает из-за созвучия выражений "властИ предержащие" и "власть имущие". То есть путают значение слов "держать" и "иметь".

Comment: Поподробнее, пожалуйста. В чем ошибка, как правильно... И с аргументами желательно.

Comment: Правильно "власти предежащие" судя по статье https://vnovgorode.ru/interesnye-materialy/14998-russkij-yazyk-novgorodtsev-kak-pravilno-i-pochemu-vlasti-prederzhashchie.html. Впрочем, это все не имеет значения. Я не нашел в словарях и в гугле глагол "предержать". Следовательно записываем "власти предежащие" в афоризмы и тогда уже не важно как правильно.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы закрыть спор о том "как правильно?" и в чём разница между власть имущими и властями предержащими, [вот вам статья об этом](https://rg.ru/2016/12/23/marinakoroleva-v-chem-raznica-vlast-imushchie-i-vlast-prederzhashchie.html)

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).