# Разрешён ли спор между филологами и словарями о власть/властях предержащих? Что последнее, окончательное?

Tags: грамотная-речь, фразеология

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Розенталь](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/56.htm):

> Фразеологизм имеет устойчивую форму, которая должна строго
>   воспроизводиться – в противном случае возникают ошибки типа *деньги
>   выпускаются в трубу* (следует: *вылетают в трубу*), *слухом не
>   слыхивал* (следует: *слыхом не слыхивал*), *душа кровью обливается*
>   (следует: *сердце кровью обливается*), *похоронить на корню* (следует:
>   *загубить на корню*), *пока суть да дело* (следует: *пока суд да дело*), *положить в долгий ящик* (следует: *отложить в долгий ящик*),
>   *отлегло на сердце* (следует: *отлегло от сердца* или *отлегло на душе*), ***власть предержащие*** (**следует**: ***власть
>   предержащая).***

---

> ... они свой конфликт *с власть предержащими*... (в зависимости от
>   значения следует: ***с властью предержащей*** или ***властями
>   предержащими***...)

Comment: А где здесь конфликт? Все источники дружно указывают, что в исходной форме "власть" (власти) в именительном падеже, а винительный ошибочен (в "творческом" употреблении выражения понаслышке).

Comment: http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=13.2

Comment: Так то ж не филологи, а _журналисты_ (безответственные  гуманитарии) - что с них взять? Они по роду занятий пребывают в контакте с не самыми лучшими образцами речи, которые потом бессознательно разносят.

Comment: http://gramota.ru/biblio/magazines/gramota/frazeologia/28_365         https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429000/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5

Comment: Серж, материал действительно интересный. Обращает на себя внимание время возникновения вольночтений по этому поводу: сразу после распада СССР. Ведь до этого на радио и телевидении за дикторами (позже начавшими именоваться тележурналистами) присматривали филологи (буквально "депремировали" за ошибки), да и прочим журналистам они не позволяли от норм отходить. А тут ещё у них в РАН нашлась заступница.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно ориентироваться на **частотность употребления в Нацкорпусе**:

1) Власти предержащие — 38 примеров (современные и дореволюционные);

2) Власть предержащая — 9 примеров (современные и дореволюционные);

3) Власть предержащие — 22 примера (современные):

Отсюда вывод: наиболее предпочтительным является вариант (1).